# How to avoid background reflection Computer display

Tags: technology, efficiency, glass, light

At work I am sitting in front of a conference room which has lots of glass wall. It is always very bright and it makes my computer display look like a mirror.  I tried playing with my display setting but it does not help.

I can not change anything in room.
Any thing which can be done to make it better for me..

[image: work location]

Comment: "I can not change anything in room." This rules out 2 options: Putting up a darker "wall" or "tarp" behind you, or turning your monitor to the left or right where (maybe) there is no window to reflect. If you turn your monitor you would also need to turn your chair and/or desk.

Comment: Would they let you work at night? No sun then!

Comment: I tried changing monitor direction .. but its not really effective. It makes it difficult for me to read any thing on display.

Comment: I believe that a white background with dark lettering will be easier to read. Vim also has daylight and evening color schemes that are specifically for managing glare. This probably won't solve your problem, but might make things tolerable while you search for something permanent.

Comment: you said it right... I am using a white background on vim, but as you said it does not solve my problem completely.

Comment: Add a matt film cover to the screen. It will not reflect then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell your employer they are likely breaking health and safety rules regarding screen glare and need to do something about it, ideally a blind on the window would be the best (as then you can also adjust it as needed).

Comment: I think thats what I will end up doing.
I will wait for couple more days and see if some one offer some solution which works without changing much in the conference room.

Comment: I'm presuming all the lights are on in the room already?

Comment: Sometimes they are on.. but it get plenty of sunlight, so it is quite bright most of the time .

Comment: This is the right suggestion. I spoke with my employer and they bought me a monitor with matt finish.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 12):

As long as you can't block the major light sources easily, then you need a [Monitor filter](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_filter) (wikipedia), which has anti glare or anti reflex/reflective behaviour. These can be bought commercially for at somewhat steep prices, or different DIY solutions available at cheaper prices.

Do a google search for [anti reflex screen](//google.com/search?q=anti+reflex+screen) to get you started, which reveals both some commercial options and a DIY anti glare solution.

Suggestions for the DIY could be to use something called quilters plastic template, which can be overlayed onto your screen and make it quite a lot better. If you have some translucent thin plastic, it is well worth to try it in front of your screen.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds bizarre, but can you tilt your monitor down a bit? It should then reflect more of the floor and your lap, and you wouldn't see the sunshine in it. (It may become difficult to read, though.)

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned, it makes it difficult for me to use display when I tilt it that much.

Comment: Then the anti-glare / anti-reflective coating that @Holroy suggested in his answer is probably the best idea.

Comment: @vikrant How about tilting it the opposite way then?
The ceiling seems dark enough.
Before monitors existed documents were often placed in such a position anyway.

Comment: I do like this picture, even if the suggestion is very bad for your work posture.

Comment: @Zaaikort I will try opposite way. Problem is that it is not always possible to keep display in one position. But I will try and see if it works for me. )

Answer (score 5):

You can knit a [privacy sock](http://gajitz.com/bizarre-knit-head-sock-is-a-cozy-bit-of-portable-laptop-privacy/). The one in the image is for a laptop, but I'm sure the design can be adapted. It's a sock that covers your head and your monitor, so no one can see your display but you. A side effect is that no significant lighting reaches your monitor.

Comment: Looking at that, it would appear that a second side effect is likely to be *overheating of laptops.* I certainly wouldn't want to use one of those with my system!

Answer (score 3):

A variant of the quilters plastic template suggested by @holroy : [punched pocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_pocket), the one which are a bit rough or "granular". It's kind of a quick/cheap fix because there is some color issue on white background (cf the picture below) but, still it does a great anti-glare job.

Cut the side
[image]

Proof of concept
[image]

On white background you will see the pixels...
[image]

... but you can find the right balance by putting some "spacers" between your screen and the punched pocket (it's just some cut cardboard and a bit of [Blu-Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu_Tack))
[image]

Other ideas: transparent matte binding cover, matt book cover, thermal laminating film.

Answer (score 1):

black ladies' stockings are a great look, even on a monitor. You may just be able to stretch one over the monitor, but if not you could cut one open and stretch it taut across the monitor and hold it in place with tape.

The matt finish of the fabric absorbs sheen, but the fineness of the mesh allows the light from your monitor to pass through. It will reduce the brightness of your monitor so you may have to compensate by increasing the monitor's own brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from this problem for years until I found out a privacy filter also kills nearly all reflections on your screen!.
Since then, I always adopt one of two options:
(a) an external monitor with antiglare screen, luckily my company has this kind of device in all "mobile worker" desks/cubicles. (they are available from all big computer vendors).
(b) the 3M privacy filter on my laptop screen, simple and the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I could not resist the temptation!

[image]

Source: https://gajitz.com/bizarre-knit-head-sock-is-a-cozy-bit-of-portable-laptop-privacy/

Answer (score 0):

You could have the windows tinted as well. Or place a partition behind you.There are polarized sunglasses that fishermen use to take the glare off the water so they can see the fish. They can be a bit expensive but may just do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are glass treatments for picture frames to prevent or greatly reduce reflections of photos and artwork. Visit your local art framing store with your screen size to have a piece of non-reflecting glass cut to fit over your screen. The edge can be polished or taped to protect your fingers or monitor finish.

Crossed polaroid screens are light and can cut the reflections by about 95% but are costly. Sheets of polaroid plastic are available from Edmund Scientifics, Barrington, New Jersey, United States.

Comment: Polaroid ... hmm, I wonder whether polaroid sunglasses would help. They might get reflections off the inside of the glasses, and screen brightness might be an issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a surface right behind you blocking any light that is bouncing against your screen. Try a wide pop-up / roll-up banner, ideally painted matt black on the side facing your screen. Either buy a new one - they are cheap - or repurpose an old one the marketing team has no use for anymore.

p.s. make sure you let your boss and colleagues know why you are doing it, so they don't think you are trying to hide behind it to play games   ;)    Health and safety (eyesight) is a very good and valid reason.

Let me know if that has worked for you.